# JSF 2.2 ViewAction not decorated with CDI interceptor

Tags: cdi, jsf-2.2, interceptor, weld

I have a JSF view with a viewAction defined as such:

```
 <f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{basketBean.onBasketViewPageLoad}" immediate="true"/>
</f:metadata>
```

The onBasketViewPageLoad method is called but it is not decorated by the CDI interceptor defined. 
Bean method

```
@CalledFromJSFView
public void onBasketViewPageLoad() throws Exception {... }
```

The annotation works, since it is registered on "normal" JSF action listeners and the like, which are invoked.

Does anyone know how to get viewActions decorated by a CDI interceptor.

For the record the interceptor is defined as such:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface CalledFromJSFView{
...
}
```

Comment: `CalledFromJSFView` is but a binding, not the interceptor itself - you might want to show the code of the interceptor itself. Also, have you tried this interceptor in other cases? Are you sure it is enabled? Does it use `@Priority` or an entry in `beans.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone with the same problem. It turns out that it was due to mis-match in the dependencies.

When it did not work I used (gradle dependencies)

```
   compile 'javax.faces:javax.faces-api:2.2';
    compile (group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-impl', version: '2.2.0')
compile group: 'org.jboss.weld.servlet', name: 'weld-servlet', version: '2.4.6.Final'
```

When it worked the javax.faces was updated to com.sun.faces.

Like this:

```
compile 'com.sun.faces:jsf-api:2.2.15'
compile (group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-impl', version: '2.2.15'
compile group: 'org.jboss.weld.servlet', name: 'weld-servlet', version: '2.4.6.Final'
```

So I guess it was due to version incompatability.